# Cloud Function with Pub/sub trigger always creates new Eventarc subscription for the Topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Google Cloud Functions triggered by Pub/Sub messages. In my workflow, When I create a Cloud Function with pubsub trigger, it automatically create a new eventarc subscription in Google Cloud Pub/Sub Topic.

I'm looking for a way to have a Cloud Function ask for a subscription in Pub/Sub during configuration .

I've searched through the Google Cloud Functions documentation and experimented with various things but it seems there's no built-in feature that allows Cloud Function to  be attached to the existing subscription.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Create a HTTP functions and configure the push subscription to its URL. There is no other way. If you create a background function, directly linked to a topic, a subscription is created automatically for Cloud Functions. It's the feature !

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for your response, but I'm still figuring things out. Actually, I'm developing a scalable notification system with cloud pubsub and cloud functions , but I'm not sure how to go for the implementation properly . I would truly appreciate any advice you could give.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere also the main question is How can I achieve one to many subscribe pattern? because I want to distribute my messages across multiple functions/subscribers by having only one subscription. So that I can send notifications more efficiently.

Comment: I subscription can push to only one HTTP endpoint (cloud function). I topic can have multiple subscription. So you can combine multiple subscription and multiple functions to push different source of message to different function. However, I won't recommend this pattern. I prefer to keep 1 type of message for 1 type of function (separation of concern.)

Comment: In your opinion, will a single cloud function be sufficient to notify consumers via email on a million-plus scale? Can it grow with it? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Yes, a single function can scale to 1000 instances in a few minutes. If you use Gen2 (or Cloud Run) you can also process up to 1000 requests concurrently over 1000 instances. 1000 * 1000 = 1M, I thinks it's ok. In addition, it scale up and down and the number of instance is automatically set according to the load (and therefore you pay only the useful resources). https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency

Comment: Thanks a lot mate it really helped me!